# Настройка PhpMyAdmin на Ubuntu 16

Tags: sql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос.

Делал все по [мануалу](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_ubuntu_server/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_lamp/phpmyadmin), использовал сервер Apache2.

При переходе на ссылку http://localhost/phpmyadmin/  выдает php скрипт, а не форму входа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код всей страницы (в генераторе для HTML для более удобного отображения):

```js
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main loader script
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/**
 * Gets some core libraries and displays a top message if required
 */
require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';

/**
 * display Git revision if requested
 */
require_once 'libraries/display_git_revision.lib.php';
require_once 'libraries/Template.class.php';

/**
 * pass variables to child pages
 */
$drops = array(
    'lang',
    'server',
    'collation_connection',
    'db',
    'table'
);
foreach ($drops as $each_drop) {
    if (array_key_exists($each_drop, $_GET)) {
        unset($_GET[$each_drop]);
    }
}
unset($drops, $each_drop);

/*
 * Black list of all scripts to which front-end must submit data.
 * Such scripts must not be loaded on home page.
 *
 */
$target_blacklist = array (
    'import.php', 'export.php'
);

// If we have a valid target, let's load that script instead
if (! empty($_REQUEST['target'])
    && is_string($_REQUEST['target'])
    && ! preg_match('/^index/', $_REQUEST['target'])
    && ! in_array($_REQUEST['target'], $target_blacklist)
    && in_array($_REQUEST['target'], $goto_whitelist)
) {
    include $_REQUEST['target'];
    exit;
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['ajax_request']) && ! empty($_REQUEST['access_time'])) {
    exit;
}

// See FAQ 1.34
if (! empty($_REQUEST['db'])) {
    $page = null;
    if (! empty($_REQUEST['table'])) {
        $page = PMA_Util::getScriptNameForOption(
            $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabTable'], 'table'
        );
    } else {
        $page = PMA_Util::getScriptNameForOption(
            $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabDatabase'], 'database'
        );
    }
    include $page;
    exit;
}

/**
 * Check if it is an ajax request to reload the recent tables list.
 */
require_once 'libraries/RecentFavoriteTable.class.php';
if ($GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] && ! empty($_REQUEST['recent_table'])) {
    $response = PMA_Response::getInstance();
    $response->addJSON(
        'list',
        PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('recent')->getHtmlList()
    );
    exit;
}

if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['git_revision']) && $GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] == true) {
        PMA_printGitRevision();
        exit;
    }
    echo '<div id="is_git_revision"></div>';
}

// Handles some variables that may have been sent by the calling script
$GLOBALS['db'] = '';
$GLOBALS['table'] = '';
$show_query = '1';

// Any message to display?
if (! empty($message)) {
    echo PMA_Util::getMessage($message);
    unset($message);
}

$common_url_query =  PMA_URL_getCommon();
$mysql_cur_user_and_host = '';

// when $server > 0, a server has been chosen so we can display
// all MySQL-related information
if ($server > 0) {
    include 'libraries/server_common.inc.php';
    include 'libraries/StorageEngine.class.php';

    // Use the verbose name of the server instead of the hostname
    // if a value is set
    $server_info = '';
    if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) {
        $server_info .= htmlspecialchars($cfg['Server']['verbose']);
        if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) {
            $server_info .= ' (';
        }
    }
    if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo'] || empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) {
        $server_info .= $GLOBALS['dbi']->getHostInfo();
    }
    if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose']) && $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) {
        $server_info .= ')';
    }
    $mysql_cur_user_and_host = $GLOBALS['dbi']->fetchValue('SELECT USER();');

    // should we add the port info here?
    $short_server_info = (!empty($GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose'])
                ? $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose']
                : $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['host']);
}

echo '<div id="maincontainer">' . "\n";
// Anchor for favorite tables synchronization.
echo PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('favorite')->getHtmlSyncFavoriteTables();
echo '<div id="main_pane_left">';
if ($server > 0 || count($cfg['Servers']) > 1
) {
    if ($cfg['DBG']['demo']) {
        echo '<div class="group">';
        echo '<h2>' . __('phpMyAdmin Demo Server') . '</h2>';
        echo '<p style="margin: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em">';
        printf(
            __(
                'You are using the demo server. You can do anything here, but '
                . 'please do not change root, debian-sys-maint and pma users. '
                . 'More information is available at %s.'
            ),
            '<a href="http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/">demo.phpmyadmin.net</a>'
        );
        echo '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '<div class="group">';
    echo '<h2>' . __('General settings') . '</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';

    /**
     * Displays the MySQL servers choice form
     */
    if ($cfg['ServerDefault'] == 0
        || (! $cfg['NavigationDisplayServers']
        && (count($cfg['Servers']) > 1
        || ($server == 0 && count($cfg['Servers']) == 1)))
    ) {
        echo '<li id="li_select_server" class="no_bullets" >';
        include_once 'libraries/select_server.lib.php';
        echo PMA_Util::getImage('s_host.png') . " " . PMA_selectServer(true, true);
        echo '</li>';
    }

    /**
     * Displays the mysql server related links
     */
    if ($server > 0 && ! PMA_DRIZZLE) {
        include_once 'libraries/check_user_privileges.lib.php';

        // Logout for advanced authentication
        if ($cfg['Server']['auth_type'] != 'config') {
            if ($cfg['ShowChgPassword']) {
                $conditional_class = 'ajax';
                PMA_printListItem(
                    PMA_Util::getImage('s_passwd.png') . "&nbsp;" . __('Change password'),
                    'li_change_password',
                    'user_password.php' . $common_url_query,
                    null,
                    null,
                    'change_password_anchor',
                    "no_bullets",
                    $conditional_class
                );
            }
        } // end if
        echo '    <li id="li_select_mysql_collation" class="no_bullets" >';
        echo '        <form method="post" action="index.php">' . "\n"
           . PMA_URL_getHiddenInputs(null, null, 4, 'collation_connection')
           . '            <label for="select_collation_connection">' . "\n"
           . '                ' . PMA_Util::getImage('s_asci.png') . "&nbsp;"
                               . __('Server connection collation') . "\n"
           // put the doc link in the form so that it appears on the same line
           . PMA_Util::showMySQLDocu('Charset-connection')
           . ': ' .  "\n"
           . '            </label>' . "\n"

           . PMA_generateCharsetDropdownBox(
               PMA_CSDROPDOWN_COLLATION,
               'collation_connection',
               'select_collation_connection',
               $collation_connection,
               true,
               true
           )
           . '        </form>' . "\n"
           . '    </li>' . "\n";
    } // end of if ($server > 0 && !PMA_DRIZZLE)
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}

echo '<div class="group">';
echo '<h2>' . __('Appearance settings') . '</h2>';
echo '  <ul>';

// Displays language selection combo
if (empty($cfg['Lang']) && count($GLOBALS['available_languages']) > 1) {
    echo '<li id="li_select_lang" class="no_bullets">';
    include_once 'libraries/display_select_lang.lib.php';
    echo PMA_Util::getImage('s_lang.png') . " " . PMA_getLanguageSelectorHtml();
    echo '</li>';
}

// ThemeManager if available

if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ThemeManager']) {
    echo '<li id="li_select_theme" class="no_bullets">';
    echo PMA_Util::getImage('s_theme.png') . " "
            .  $_SESSION['PMA_Theme_Manager']->getHtmlSelectBox();
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '<li id="li_select_fontsize">';
echo PMA_Config::getFontsizeForm();
echo '</li>';

echo '</ul>';

// User preferences

if ($server > 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    PMA_printListItem(
        PMA_Util::getImage('b_tblops.png') . "&nbsp;" . __('More settings'),
        'li_user_preferences',
        'prefs_manage.php' . $common_url_query,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "no_bullets"
    );
    echo '</ul>';
}

echo '</div>';


echo '</div>';
echo '<div id="main_pane_right">';


if ($server > 0 && $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) {

    echo '<div class="group">';
    echo '<h2>' . __('Database server') . '</h2>';
    echo '<ul>' . "\n";
    PMA_printListItem(
        __('Server:') . ' ' . $server_info,
        'li_server_info'
    );
    PMA_printListItem(
        __('Server type:') . ' ' . PMA_Util::getServerType(),
        'li_server_type'
    );
    PMA_printListItem(
        __('Server version:')
        . ' '
        . PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION . ' - ' . PMA_MYSQL_VERSION_COMMENT,
        'li_server_version'
    );
    PMA_printListItem(
        __('Protocol version:') . ' ' . $GLOBALS['dbi']->getProtoInfo(),
        'li_mysql_proto'
    );
    PMA_printListItem(
        __('User:') . ' ' . htmlspecialchars($mysql_cur_user_and_host),
        'li_user_info'
    );

    echo '    <li id="li_select_mysql_charset">';
    echo '        ' . __('Server charset:') . ' '
       . '        <span lang="en" dir="ltr">';
    if (! PMA_DRIZZLE) {
        echo '           '
            . $mysql_charsets_descriptions[$mysql_charset_map['utf-8']];
    }
    echo '           (' . $mysql_charset_map['utf-8'] . ')'
       . '        </span>'
       . '    </li>'
       . '  </ul>'
       . ' </div>';
}

if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo'] || $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowPhpInfo']) {
    echo '<div class="group">';
    echo '<h2>' . __('Web server') . '</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) {
        PMA_printListItem($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'li_web_server_software');

        if ($server > 0) {
            $client_version_str = $GLOBALS['dbi']->getClientInfo();
            if (preg_match('#\d+\.\d+\.\d+#', $client_version_str)) {
                $client_version_str = 'libmysql - ' . $client_version_str;
            }
            PMA_printListItem(
                __('Database client version:') . ' ' . $client_version_str,
                'li_mysql_client_version'
            );

            $php_ext_string = __('PHP extension:') . ' ';
            if (PMA_DatabaseInterface::checkDbExtension('mysqli')) {
                $extension = 'mysqli';
            } else {
                $extension = 'mysql';
            }
            $php_ext_string  .= $extension . ' '
                . PMA_Util::showPHPDocu('book.' . $extension . '.php');

            PMA_printListItem(
                $php_ext_string,
                'li_used_php_extension'
            );

            $php_version_string = __('PHP version:') . ' ' . phpversion();

            PMA_printListItem(
                $php_version_string,
                'li_used_php_version'
            );
        }
    }

    if ($cfg['ShowPhpInfo']) {
        PMA_printListItem(
            __('Show PHP information'),
            'li_phpinfo',
            'phpinfo.php' . $common_url_query,
            null,
            '_blank'
        );
    }
    echo '  </ul>';
    echo ' </div>';
}

echo '<div class="group pmagroup">';
echo '<h2>phpMyAdmin</h2>';
echo '<ul>';
$class = null;
// We rely on CSP to allow access to http://www.phpmyadmin.net, but IE lacks
// support here and does not allow request to http once using https.
if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['VersionCheck']
    && (! $GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->get('is_https') || PMA_USR_BROWSER_AGENT != 'IE')
) {
    $class = 'jsversioncheck';
}
PMA_printListItem(
    __('Version information:') . ' <span class="version">' . PMA_VERSION . '</span>',
    'li_pma_version',
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    $class
);
PMA_printListItem(
    __('Documentation'),
    'li_pma_docs',
    PMA_Util::getDocuLink('index'),
    null,
    '_blank'
);
PMA_printListItem(
    __('Wiki'),
    'li_pma_wiki',
    PMA_linkURL('http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/'),
    null,
    '_blank'
);

// does not work if no target specified, don't know why
PMA_printListItem(
    __('Official Homepage'),
    'li_pma_homepage',
    PMA_linkURL('http://www.phpMyAdmin.net/'),
    null,
    '_blank'
);
PMA_printListItem(
    __('Contribute'),
    'li_pma_contribute',
    PMA_linkURL('https://www.phpmyadmin.net/contribute/'),
    null,
    '_blank'
);
PMA_printListItem(
    __('Get support'),
    'li_pma_support',
    PMA_linkURL('https://www.phpmyadmin.net/support/'),
    null,
    '_blank'
);
PMA_printListItem(
    __('List of changes'),
    'li_pma_changes',
    'changelog.php' . PMA_URL_getCommon(),
    null,
    '_blank'
);
echo '    </ul>';
echo ' </div>';

echo '</div>';

echo '</div>';

/**
 * Warning if using the default MySQL privileged account
 */
if ($server != 0
    && $cfg['Server']['user'] == 'root'
    && $cfg['Server']['password'] == ''
) {
    trigger_error(
        __(
            'You are connected as \'root\' with no password, which'
            . ' corresponds to the default MySQL privileged account.'
            . ' Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to'
            . ' intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by'
            . ' setting a password for user \'root\'.'
        ),
        E_USER_WARNING
    );
}

/**
 * As we try to handle charsets by ourself, mbstring overloads just
 * break it, see bug 1063821.
 */
if (@extension_loaded('mbstring') && @ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') > 1) {
    trigger_error(
        __(
            'You have enabled mbstring.func_overload in your PHP '
            . 'configuration. This option is incompatible with phpMyAdmin '
            . 'and might cause some data to be corrupted!'
        ),
        E_USER_WARNING
    );
}

/**
 * mbstring is used for handling multibytes inside parser, so it is good
 * to tell user something might be broken without it, see bug #1063149.
 */
if (! @extension_loaded('mbstring')) {
    trigger_error(
        __(
            'The mbstring PHP extension was not found and you seem to be using'
            . ' a multibyte charset. Without the mbstring extension phpMyAdmin'
            . ' is unable to split strings correctly and it may result in'
            . ' unexpected results.'
        ),
        E_USER_WARNING
    );
}

if ($cfg['LoginCookieValidityDisableWarning'] == false) {
    /**
     * Check whether session.gc_maxlifetime limits session validity.
     */
    $gc_time = (int)@ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
    if ($gc_time < $GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieValidity'] ) {
        trigger_error(
            __(
                'Your PHP parameter [a@http://php.net/manual/en/session.' .
                'configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime@_blank]session.' .
                'gc_maxlifetime[/a] is lower than cookie validity configured ' .
                'in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login might expire sooner ' .
                'than configured in phpMyAdmin.'
            ),
            E_USER_WARNING
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Check whether LoginCookieValidity is limited by LoginCookieStore.
 */
if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieStore'] != 0
    && $GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieStore'] < $GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieValidity']
) {
    trigger_error(
        __(
            'Login cookie store is lower than cookie validity configured in ' .
            'phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login will expire sooner than ' .
            'configured in phpMyAdmin.'
        ),
        E_USER_WARNING
    );
}

/**
 * Check if user does not have defined blowfish secret and it is being used.
 */
if (! empty($_SESSION['encryption_key'])
    && empty($GLOBALS['cfg']['blowfish_secret'])
) {
    trigger_error(
        __(
            'The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).'
        ),
        E_USER_WARNING
    );
}

/**
 * Check for existence of config directory which should not exist in
 * production environment.
 */
if (file_exists('config')) {
    trigger_error(
        __(
            'Directory [code]config[/code], which is used by the setup script, ' .
            'still exists in your phpMyAdmin directory. It is strongly ' .
            'recommended to remove it once phpMyAdmin has been configured. ' .
            'Otherwise the security of your server may be compromised by ' .
            'unauthorized people downloading your configuration.'
        ),
        E_USER_WARNING
    );
}

if ($server > 0) {
    $cfgRelation = PMA_getRelationsParam();
    if (! $cfgRelation['allworks']
        && $cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] == false
    ) {
        $msg_text = __(
            'The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely '
            . 'configured, some extended features have been deactivated. '
            . '%sFind out why%s. '
        );
        if ($cfg['ZeroConf'] == true) {
            $msg_text .= '<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' .
                __(
                    'Or alternately go to \'Operations\' tab of any database '
                    . 'to set it up there.'
                );
        }
        $msg = PMA_Message::notice($msg_text);
        $msg->addParam(
            '<a href="' . $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] . 'chk_rel.php'
            . $common_url_query . '">',
            false
        );
        $msg->addParam('</a>', false);
        /* Show error if user has configured something, notice elsewhere */
        if (!empty($cfg['Servers'][$server]['pmadb'])) {
            $msg->isError(true);
        }
        $msg->display();
    } // end if
}

/**
 * Warning about different MySQL library and server version
 * (a difference on the third digit does not count).
 * If someday there is a constant that we can check about mysqlnd,
 * we can use it instead of strpos().
 * If no default server is set, $GLOBALS['dbi'] is not defined yet.
 * Drizzle can speak MySQL protocol, so don't warn about version mismatch for
 * Drizzle servers.
 * We also do not warn if MariaDB is detected, as it has its own version
 * numbering.
 */
if (isset($GLOBALS['dbi'])
    && !PMA_DRIZZLE
    && $cfg['ServerLibraryDifference_DisableWarning'] == false
) {
    /** @var PMA_String $pmaString */
    $pmaString = $GLOBALS['PMA_String'];

    $_client_info = $GLOBALS['dbi']->getClientInfo();
    if ($server > 0
        && /*overload*/mb_strpos($_client_info, 'mysqlnd') === false
        && /*overload*/mb_strpos(PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION, 'MariaDB') === false
        && substr(PMA_MYSQL_CLIENT_API, 0, 3) != substr(
            PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION, 0, 3
        )
    ) {
        trigger_error(
            PMA_sanitize(
                sprintf(
                    __(
                        'Your PHP MySQL library version %s differs from your ' .
                        'MySQL server version %s. This may cause unpredictable ' .
                        'behavior.'
                    ),
                    $_client_info,
                    substr(
                        PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION,
                        0,
                        strpos(PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION . '-', '-')
                    )
                )
            ),
            E_USER_NOTICE
        );
    }
    unset($_client_info);
}

/**
 * Warning about Suhosin only if its simulation mode is not enabled
 */
if ($cfg['SuhosinDisableWarning'] == false
    && @ini_get('suhosin.request.max_value_length')
    && @ini_get('suhosin.simulation') == '0'
) {
    trigger_error(
        sprintf(
            __(
                'Server running with Suhosin. Please refer to %sdocumentation%s ' .
                'for possible issues.'
            ),
            '[doc@faq1-38]',
            '[/doc]'
        ),
        E_USER_WARNING
    );
}

/**
 * Warning about incomplete translations.
 *
 * The data file is created while creating release by ./scripts/remove-incomplete-mo
 */
if (file_exists('libraries/language_stats.inc.php')) {
    include 'libraries/language_stats.inc.php';
    /*
     * This message is intentionally not translated, because we're
     * handling incomplete translations here and focus on english
     * speaking users.
     */
    if (isset($GLOBALS['language_stats'][$lang])
        && $GLOBALS['language_stats'][$lang] < $cfg['TranslationWarningThreshold']
    ) {
        trigger_error(
            'You are using an incomplete translation, please help to make it '
            . 'better by [a@https://www.phpmyadmin.net/translate/'
            . '@_blank]contributing[/a].',
            E_USER_NOTICE
        );
    }
}

/**
 * prints list item for main page
 *
 * @param string $name            displayed text
 * @param string $listId          id, used for css styles
 * @param string $url             make item as link with $url as target
 * @param string $mysql_help_page display a link to MySQL's manual
 * @param string $target          special target for $url
 * @param string $a_id            id for the anchor,
 *                                used for jQuery to hook in functions
 * @param string $class           class for the li element
 * @param string $a_class         class for the anchor element
 *
 * @return void
 */
function PMA_printListItem($name, $listId = null, $url = null,
    $mysql_help_page = null, $target = null, $a_id = null, $class = null,
    $a_class = null
) {
    echo PMA\Template::get('list/item')
        ->render(
            array(
                'content' => $name,
                'id' => $listId,
                'class' => $class,
                'url' => array(
                    'href' => $url,
                    'target' => $target,
                    'id' => $a_id,
                    'class' => $a_class,
                ),
                'mysql_help_page' => $mysql_help_page,
            )
        );
}
```

Как думаете, в чем может быть проблема?

Php, MySQL server, phpMyAdmin установлены.

Comment: Попробуй установить это lamp-пакетом. phpMyAdmin должен работать.

Comment: @СашаВдодович Так я ведь им и ставил. Или я что-то не понимаю. 
В мануале, что по ссылке, указано, что lamp-пакетом.

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что Апач не понимает, что надо делать с файлами *.php. В конфигах Апача есть директива похожая на `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` ? В мануале, что по ссылке, речь идет только про `apt-get install phpmyadmin` и не сказано, про php, mod-php и т.д. Посмотрите в мануал https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04 - Step 3: Install PHP

Comment: @defrag Ваш ответ помог. Спасибо. 
Можете оформить в виде ответа, зачту. 
Спасибо за помощь ещё раз. )